# creating Java Proxy instance for a class type?

Tags: java, easymock, proxy-classes

I have the following code that works for creating a Proxy instance for an interface type backed by an `InvocationHandler` implementation, however when I use a concrete class type it doesn't work and this is well known and documented in [Proxy.newProxyInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance%28java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D,%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler%29):

```
    // NOTE: does not work because SomeConcreteClass is not an interface type
    final ClassLoader myClassLoader = SomeConcreteClass.getClassLoader();
    SomeConcreteClass myProxy = (SomeConcreteClass) Proxy.newProxyInstance(myClassLoader, new Class[] {
        SomeConcreteClass.class }, new InvocationHandler() { /* TODO */ });
```

However, if I recall correctly I have seen this use-case work in some mock frameworks where it is possible to mock a concrete class type e.g. [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/). Before checking up their source code can anyone indicate what needs to be done to proxy also concrete class types and not only interfaces?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JDK dynamic proxies only work with interfaces.  If you want to create a proxy with a concrete superclass you need to use something like [CGLIB](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) instead.

```
Enhancer e = new Enhancer();
e.setClassLoader(myClassLoader);
e.setSuperclass(SomeConcreteClass.class);
e.setCallback(new MethodInterceptor() {
  public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args,
        MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
    return proxy.invokeSuper(obj, args);
  }
});
// create proxy using SomeConcreteClass() no-arg constructor
SomeConcreteClass myProxy = (SomeConcreteClass)e.create();
// create proxy using SomeConcreteClass(String) constructor
SomeConcreteClass myProxy2 = (SomeConcreteClass)e.create(
    new Class<?>[] {String.class},
    new Object[] { "hello" });
```

Comment: then the OP question would be: how CGLIB does it in terms of pure Java :)

Comment: @GiovanniAzua it dynamically generates the bytecode for the proxy subclass using the ASM bytecode manipulation library.